# Post hoc test for robust 3 way ANOVA

Tags: r, anova, post-hoc, robust

I am doing a 3x2x2 between subject study. To make thing simple, I name my variables as A, B and C here.  Using the `WRS 2` package in R, I have gotten results for the 3 way robust ANOVA (`t3way`). One of the two-way interactions and the three way interaction were significant. The t3way anova result showed a significant result between AB and ABC with p-value of .031 and .051 respectively.

When come to the post hoc test, I was made understood that there is no post hoc test available for 3 way robust ANOVA in R and hence, I have to split the file by the third IV for the two way ANOVA and post hoc tests. I split the data with variable C (i.e. Ci and Cii) and the t2way anova result of Ci is:

A   .394(p-value)

B   .618

AB  .019

t2way anova for Cii din't show any significant.

When I performed `mcp2atm` (post hoc test) on the separate robust 2 way ANOVAs, I didn't get a single contrast that is significant.  Post hoc test (mcp2atm) result for Ci showed:

```
    V1       ci.lower ci.upper p-value
```

A1                1.00000 -1.11291  3.11291 0.22754

A2                1.33333 -0.87160  3.53827 0.12861

A3                0.33333 -2.56160  3.22827 0.77417

B1               -0.33333 -2.68024  2.01358 0.77417

A1:B1             0.33333 -1.77957  2.44624 0.68124

A2:B1             0.00000 -2.20493  2.20493 1.00000

A3:B1            -0.33333 -3.22827  2.56160 0.77417

I am puzzled and do not know how to continue with the analysis.

Comment: Can you paste in your output? A significant omnibus test without a significant post-hoc isn't necessarily unusual, but it's going to be hard to explain without more information.

Comment: Please edit your Q & paste the output into it.